# Reverse this in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a snippet that replaces a select menus text when changed. I'm looking for a simple way of change it back when the select is clicked again.

**jQuery**

```
$('.youth').change(function(){    
    $(".youth option").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("(12-15yr)", "  ");
    $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="youth element">
  <option selected>Youth</option>
  <option value="1">0</option>
  <option value="1">1 (12-15yr)</option>
  <option value="2">2 (12-15yr)</option>
  <option value="3">3 (12-15yr)</option>
  <option value="4">4 (12-15yr)</option>
  <option value="5">5 (12-15yr)</option>
  <option value="6">6 (12-15yr)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this?

Comment: It's a styling issue. I need to simply have the number displayed after the change but if a visitor wants to change their mind I need the ages displayed again.

Comment: replace may not impelemnted in Internet explorer < 9. Replace replaces via Regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an origin attributes :

```
<option value="3" origin="3 (12-15yr)">3 (12-15yr)</option>
```

You can do this :

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MjCxZ/

```
$('.youth').on('focus',function(){ 
    $(".youth option").each(function() {     
          $(this).text($(this).attr('origin'));
    });
}); 


$('.youth').on('change',function(){ 
    $(".youth option").each(function() {         
         var text = $(this).text();
                    text = text.replace("(12-15yr)", "  ");
                        $(this).text(text);
    });
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect, it's just when the menu is selected again the ages show up.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
     $('.youth').blur(function () {
        $(".youth option").each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            text = text.replace("(12-15yr)", "  ");
            $(this).text(text);
        });
    });
    $('.youth').focus(function () {
        $(".youth option").each(function () {
            $(this).text($(this).text().match(/\(12-15yr\)$/) ? $(this).text() : $(this).text() + "(12-15yr)");
        });
    });
```